# I keep getting a permission denied (public key) error in my git bash

Tags: github, ssh

I'm getting message

```
permission denied (public key)
```

when I try to push to git hub or clone,
at first i thought it was the destination file the key was in, but when i used:

```
$SSH -T git@github.com -i(file path)
```

I got the same error. 
The weird thing is, when I first set up git I cloned down my repository, but could not push it because of the public key error. Now I can't clone or push any repositories.

- I have already generated the ssh key in git bash and linked it to git hub
- I have configured my user name and email
- I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Did you try to git clone from something like "git://github.com/larryjones860/XXXX.git" OR did you use http://..... I find that http doesn't work for pushing sometimes, I.e. it could be that you checked it out as a read only git clone.

Comment: Well, at least we know that you have SSH problems (assuming that the `$SSH` was the ssh program). I would try `$SSH -T -v git@github.com -i(file path)` to see the details of ssh's problems.

Comment: Make sure your private key has been `chmod go-rwx`d - your SSH client may refuse to use a private key readable by others.

Comment: Use the diagnostic output of `ssh -v git@github.com` to get a better understanding of what went wrong